# What changes to make?

Tags: ubuntu, cassandra, virtualization, datastax, kvm

- Cassandra is installed on a Virtual Machine ( IP address - 192.168.a.b) created using KVM on a Ubuntu host (H1) machine ( IP address - p.q.r.s)
- Send cassandra stress command from another Ubuntu machine (H2)( IP address - p.q.r.t) which is in same network as H1
- Ports 7000 and 9042 on H1 are forwarded to the same ports on the virtual machine using iptables on H1
- When the listen_address and rpc_address of cassandra.yaml is set to the IP address of H1 (p.q.r.s) the following error is displayed

> Unable to bind to address /p.q.r.s:7000 . Set listen_address in cassandra.yaml to an interface you can bind to, e.g., your private IP address on EC2​

- My experiment requires a cluster of Cassandra on virtual machine installed on 3 host machines described like above. ( 1 VM per host machine)

Comment: You cannot bind to H1's IP address. Cassandra is not aware of that. Try binding it to an interface like eth0. I made an internal network on virtual box and configured the IP addresses manually just to make the cluster work.

Comment: Hey @Sreekar Thanks for the comment. How do you think I can bind it to the interface? I am using the machines in my university, so cant actually configure the IP addresses of the host machines and neither can I get new public addresses for the Virtual machines. Thank you

Comment: Try bridged networking, it will be easy, you will get a new IP address for your VM and it will be directly visible on the LAN. If that is not possible, you can give "eth0" or "eth1" at listen_interface to bind it to interface. Make sure you don't have any firewall running on VM, Still with this method, I'm not sure whether it will work though.

Comment: @Sreekar Does bridging the network on the host involve assigning a public IP to the VM? Because I think I cannot do that. I tried changing the listen_interface and it did not work as it could not find the interface. Thank you

Comment: In bridged netoworking, your VM will get it's own IP from the local DHCP server. If it's not possible, I mean if DHCP server rejects unknown servers on network, then bridged networking is not an option for you :(

Comment: Hey @Sreekar. I think I found a way to get a public IP for my virtual machines. So, all I need to do is form a cluster with the public IP's like I normally do. Thank you for the support though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only possible way I found was to assign public IP addresses to the virtual machines and use them.